# Is $C_0^\infty(0,T;H)$ dense in $L^2(0,T;H)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Is the space $\mathcal{D}(0,T;H) = C_0^\infty(0,T;H)$ dense in $L^2(0,T;H)?$

I am aware that this space is dense in the space of differentiable Bochner functions but I don't want that..

Comment: I think that this embedding is dense. Have you tried to prove it via folding with a smooth mollifier?